# Connect to my company's intranet LAN-only web site from outside with ssh tunnel

Tags: apache-http-server, ssh, remote, port, tunnel

My company has an intranet web server, only accessible from the LAN, used for web development as an integration server. Users in the LAN set their /etc/hosts to use the same Virtual Hosts defined in the integration server's Apache config, and so be able to connect to it using the standard port 80.

I work remotely sometimes, and can access the server through SSH using a custom port.

If I set my /etc/hosts to the public IP of that server, is there any way I could use the SSH connection with that custom port so that my browser connection is tunneled through it gets pages from that web server?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't quite understood your configuration but when you ssh to the company server you should be able to set up a ssh tunnel so that you can use browser to access company webserver.

You do *not* need to set up /etc/hosts on your local machine. Using the ssh parameter

```
-L port:host:hostport
```

All traffic to port on localhost is tunnelled to host/hostport on the remote. So, when you do

```
 ssh -L 80:web-server:80 user@ssh-server -p 22
```

`http://localhost` will be redirected to the `web-server:80`. Note that the hostport is translated on the remote server, i.e. the ssh server.

`-p 22` is not needed if the ssh server uses the default port, but the question does say that the SSH server goes through a custom port. In that case, change `22` for the custom port.

If the system complains that *Privileged ports can only be forwarded by root*, run it as superuser:

```
sudo ssh -L 80:web-server:80 user@ssh-server -p 12345
```

or log as root.

Comment: The problem is the vhost on server side. It expects the HTTP query to include the correct server statement. Therefore the used hostname must be included in hosts file or the HTTP request must be altered.

Answer (score 1):

SSH command-line version:

```
ssh -L 90:devserver:80 remotehost.example.com
```

Now browse to http://devserver:90/

Remember that /etc/hosts must point to 127.0.0.1

With PuTTY, under SSH Tunnels:

1. In Source Port enter 90
2. In Destination enter devserver:80
3. Click Add
4. Remember to go back to session and click save.

Better than all the tunneling would be to get OpenVPN setup at the office.

Comment: The ssh command syntax is wrong, the `-L 90:devserver:80` etc needs to come *before* `remotehost.example.com`. Also the /etc/hosts modification is not really necessary, better to not make any change there and use http://localhost:90

Comment: @Hemal Pandya: Some Windows programs *cough cough* MSIE *cough cough* treat the literal value `localhost` as a special case (fixed in IE9 I think, but still applicable for older versions).

Comment: @Piskvor I don't know what special treatment MSIE give localhost but as others have pointed out the server may also expect to be called by a certain name so I stand corrected on that point.

Comment: @Hemal Pandya: IIRC it will always ignore any proxy when given http://localhost. The expected `Host` header that you mention is also a good point, haven't though of that.

Answer (score 0):

I do the exact opposite. When at a customer I set up a secure ssh tunnel through tunnelier on my laptop to point to an external server with ssh server installed. Then I setup switchy in google chrome to enable forwarded traffic from my browser to the external server routed through ssh.

So,

1. Install switchy in your chrome browser (You could set up a proxy in ff/ie - switchy lets you easily switch between proxy configurations). Set SOCKS Host to 127.0.0.1 and port to 1080.
2. Setup Tunnelier client on your remote machine ie. your laptop / home computer and connect it to the company ssh server. Use port 1080 with "SOCKS / HTTP Proxy Forwarding" enabled.

Hope this helps.